# AKS Multiple Nginx Ingress with internal LB

Tags: kubernetes, aks, helm, nginx-ingress

Azure Kubernetes - AKS - K8s version - 1.20.9.

Trying to setup multiple nginx ingress with Internal LB.

ingress controller with ingress-class -

```
helm install test1  ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --set controller.replicaCount=1  \
     --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
     --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
     --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=test1 \
     --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=true
```

after installation LB services and Ingress Class created.

**service** -

```
test1-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.52.125    10.240.0.4      80:32472/TCP,443:30586/TCP   4h9m
test1-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.32.211    <none>          443/TCP                      4h9m
```

**IngressClass** -

```
NAME    CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
test1   k8s.io/test1           <none>       155m
```

**Ingress file**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress-my-external
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: test1
  rules:
   - host: test1.com
     http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: aks-helloworld
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-demo
          servicePort: 80
        path: /hello-world-two(/|$)(.*)
```

**Ingress-2**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress-my-external
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: test2
  rules:
   - host: test2.com
     http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: helloworld
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: demo
          servicePort: 80
        path: /hello(/|$)(.*)
```

after creating ingress only first ip showing

```
NAME                              CLASS   HOSTS       ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
external-ingress                  test1   test4.com  10.0.240.6        80      67m
hello-world-ingress-my-external   test2   test3.com  10.0.240.6        80      104
```

Traffic not updating based on IngressClass. please help, why same ip for all ingress ? also how can serve traffic based on ingressclass ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** - I am able to manage traffics with multiple ingress after updating

```
--set controller.ingressClass=test \
 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=test --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="k8s.io/test-controller"
```

final helm command

```
helm install test1 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.ingressClass=test1 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=test1 --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="k8s.io/test1-controller" \ 
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=true
```

**Still Ingress not showing ip**

```
NAME                              CLASS     HOSTS       ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
external-ingress                  test1 test3.com             80      19m
hello-world-ingress-my-external   test2 test1.com             80      33m
```

Comment: did you install a second ingress controller with the class name test2?

Comment: yes, install second ingress class test2

Comment: From your command I don't see the second ingress controller installation using helm

Comment: i used below command. use name test 1 and test 2. Now only issue is Ingress not showing ip 
`helm install test2 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.ingressClass=test1 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=test2 --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="k8s.io/test2-controller" \ 
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=true`

Comment: could you check the service of the second ingress controller? kubectl get svc

Comment: yes checked. pods and services status are healthy . Only issue is, not assigning ip to ingress ( showing first ingress ip to all other ingress )